# Passing values to Specflow Scenario methods from feature file

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I have a custom tag defined in my Hook.cs file  like

```
 [BeforeScenario("AfterUpgradeTag")]
 public void BeforeScenarioAfterUpgrade()
 {
  // Code execution here
 }
```

What I want to do is I want to change its method definition like

```
 [BeforeScenario("AfterUpgradeTag")]
 public void BeforeScenarioAfterUpgrade(bool flag)
 {
  if(flag)
  // Code execution here
  else
  //Do a clean up 
 }
```

And I want to use this in feature file as something like

```
@AfterUpgradeTag(bool val = false)
```

I have searched alot for this. I want to know is this possible using Specflow  or if there are any alternatives

Comment: Tags are typically used in feature files, and SpecFlow does not support this kind of usage. What would the flag ever be set to `false`? Maybe if we know more about what you are trying to accomplish we can come up with some sort of answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can pass parameters like that in feature file but you can utilize tags to achieve your goal

In feature file do this

```
 @upgrade @false
  Scenario: testing upgrade
```

In binding class

```
 public static ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
```

and binding class constructor

```
 public BindingClass(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {

            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;

        }
```

and your  BeforeScenario method is defined like this in the class `BindingClass`

```
[BeforeScenario("upgrade")]
        public void BeforeScenarioUpgradeFalseorTrue()
        {
            if (BindingClass._scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("false"))
            {
                log.Info("upgrade is false..");
            }

            if (BindingClass._scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("true"))
            {
                log.Info("upgrade is true..");
            }
        }
```

when you want to pass `true` in feature file just do

```
 @upgrade @true
  Scenario: testing upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the [documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Scoped-Step-Definitions.html) from specflow to achieve this.