# Pass parameter to Specflow BeforeScenario method

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I have a Specflow BDD test where I check if a process is running and if so, kill it.

This currently happens in one of the steps:

```
[Given(@"Application ""(.*)"" application runs version ""(.*)""")]
public void WhenApplicationRunsVersion(string publisher, string version)
{
    var ApplicationOptions = new ApplicationOptions();
    _configuration.GetSection("Application").Bind(ApplicationOptions);
    var processRunning = TestHelper.ProcessRunning(publisher);
    if (processRunning)
    {
        TestHelper.KillProcess(publisher);
    }
    var result = TestHelper.ExecuteShellCommand(ApplicationOptions.FilePath.ToString() + version + "\\",
                                                ApplicationOptions.Filename.ToString(),
                                                timeout: 150000);
    processRunning = TestHelper.ProcessRunning(publisher);
    processRunning.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

I want to pull this out and run in a `BeforeScenario` method though. I created this in my Hooks.cs file

```
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public static void BeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        TestHelper.KillProcess(scenarioContext);
    }
}
```

This is my TestHelper:

```
public class TestHelper
{
    public static async Task<ProcessResult> ExecuteShellCommand(string path, string command, string arguments="", int timeout=1000, bool insertWait=false)
    {
        var result = new ProcessResult();

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = path + command;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var outputCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                // The output stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    outputCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    outputBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var errorCloseEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                // The error stream has been closed i.e. the process has terminated
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    errorCloseEvent.SetResult(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    errorBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
                }
            };

            bool isStarted;

            try
            {
                isStarted = process.Start(); 
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                // Usually it occurs when an executable file is not found or is not executable

                result.Completed = true;
                result.ExitCode = -1;
                result.Output = error.Message;

                isStarted = false;
            }

            if (isStarted)
            {
                // Reads the output stream first and then waits because deadlocks are possible
                //process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                if (insertWait)
                {

                    StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
                    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    result.Output = output;

                    // Creates task to wait for process exit using timeout
                    var waitForExit = WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);

                    // Create task to wait for process exit and closing all output streams
                    var processTask = Task.WhenAll(waitForExit, outputCloseEvent.Task, errorCloseEvent.Task);

                    // Waits process completion and then checks it was not completed by timeout
                    if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), processTask) == processTask && waitForExit.Result)
                    {
                        result.Completed = true;
                        result.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;

                        // Adds process output if it was completed with error
                        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                        {
                            result.Output = $"{outputBuilder}{errorBuilder}";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Kill hung process
                            process.Kill();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static Task<bool> WaitForExitAsync(Process process, int timeout)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit(timeout));
    }


    public struct ProcessResult
    {
        public bool Completed;
        public int? ExitCode;
        public string Output;
    }

    public static void KillProcess(string processName)
    {
        foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }

    public static bool ProcessRunning(string processName)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need the process name in order to run `TestHelper.KillProcess()`. How can I pass that to my `BeforeScenario()` method?

Comment: Why do you want to move it to a `BeforeScenario` method? What do you expect to gain?

Comment: You might be  able to achieve this using tags. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59876532/261050.

Comment: I got to the BeforeScenario first. This isn't essential. Next I'll want to add something similar to the AfterScenario. What I'll want to add there is currently a scenario step so if a step before it fails that step won't be executed so I'll want to move it to ensure it always gets run so I'll still have this query.

Answer (score 0):

This logic might be easier to handle in the `TestHelper` class. The ExecuteShellCommand method is in the best position to kill a process that is currently running and start a new one.

This method can assign the process name or Id to a static field so when you attempt to run the same command again it kills the currently running process. Furthermore, it is in the best position to throw an exception of the process doesn't start properly. You would need to post the code in your TestHelper class before I could give you a code example.

It just feels like a SpecFlow hook is the wrong place to handle this. TestHelper seems to be the better place.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Burghardt. I added the TestHelper class to my question